# Loop into array object then check if there's a equal value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Question, I have this array object, I want to find out which of this array have a similar values
then make them as one.

Example

```
[0:
        cartProduct: {
    category: "chair"
    color: "navy"
    id: "628a1738fd8299ae6659d994"
    image: "http://localhost:5000/../public/Product_chair_communal-navy.jpg"
    name: "The Communal"
    price: "4.30"
    }
        quantity: 1,
        1:
        cartProduct: {{
    category: "chair"
    color: "navy"
    id: "628a1738fd8299ae6659d994"
    image: "http://localhost:5000/../public/Product_chair_communal-navy.jpg"
    name: "The Communal"
    price: "4.30"
    }
        quantity: 1,
```

]
For example the data above I want to know if they have the similar values interms of color if yes then only return one value.

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by similar? something like `blu` === `blue` ? Also, could you style better your JSON, using the code block?

Comment: Yap, I want to loop into the arrays then find out if there's a similarities then only return single array

Comment: In your example, the `0:` and `1:` are very distracting to me.  It's neither valid JavaScript nor valid JSON.  It would be more helpful if you described your object with some sort of valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this loop:

```js
let uniqueArray = [];

dataArray.forEach((item, indx) => {
  let colorsArray = [];
  if (colorsArray.includes(item.color)) {
    continue;
  }
  uniqueArray.push(item);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest, or most performant approach:

```
// function to group the items
const groupCartItems = (items, byProperties = ['color', 'id']) => {

    // utility funciton
    const verifyEquality = (itemA, itemB) => {
        let isEqual = true;
        byProperties.forEach((prop) => {
            if (itemA.cartProduct[prop] != itemB.cartProduct[prop]) {
                isEqual = false;
                break;
            }
        });
        return isEqual;
    };

    const groupedItems = [];

    items.forEach((item) => {
        // if item has been added, skip
        if (groupedItems.find((i) => verifyEquality(item, i))) {
            return;
        }
        // find equal items
        const equals = items.filter((i) => verifyEquality(item, i));
        // sum quantities
        const quantity = equals.reduce((previousValue, data) => previousValue + data.quantity, 0);
        // push
        groupedItems.push({
            cartProduct: item.cartProduct,
            quantity,
        });
    });

    return groupedItems;
};
```

For the 'similarity' stuff, I would recommend not to do this, because it is just not a good practise. Have your values equal or else!!!

Now seriously, check [string-similarity](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-similarity). From documentation, you would only need to change the `if` inside `verifyEquality` function to:

```
import stringSimilarity from 'string-similarity';

// tweak this value to change how similar strings should be to be considered equal
const EQUALITY_RATIO = 0.75;

// ....

if (stringSimilarity.compareTwoStrings(itemA.cartProduct[prop], itemB.cartProduct[prop]) < EQUALITY_RATIO) {
}
```